# how can an unrelated table specified in FROM-clause affect the outcome of SUM()?

Tags: sql

I am new to sqlite3 and have made some queries where the outcome seems strange to me. I have two tables, OrderDetails and Offices, that from their schema are unrelated. There are 7 entries in offices and 2996 in OrderDetails. Within OrderDetails, there is a column with quantityOrdered, and by summing the column values I get an accumulated value.

```
SELECT SUM(quantityOrdered) FROM OrderDetails; (result is 105516)
```

When I include the other table, which i don't actually extract any information from in my SELECT-clause and should be unrelated in attributes like so:

```
SELECT SUM(OD.quantityOrdered FROM OrderDetails OD, Offices; (result is 738612)
```

The result is much higher, and it is interesting to see that it is exactly 7 times larger (the number of entries in offices). I also get it even though I specify that it should only be OrderDetails attributes (OD.quantityOrdered). Is there some obvious logic that I don't see and understand? I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the sum for a CROSS JOIN since you dont have a JOIN condition.
Every row FROM the first table is JOINed to every other row from the other table.

Look [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for a basic JOIN tutorial.
It should be

```
SELECT SUM(OD.quantityOrdered)
 FROM OrderDetails OD JOIN Offices O 
 ON OD.somecol=O.someothercol
```

Answer (score 1):

When you list two tables in a FROM clause but specify no conditions to relate them together, you get what is known as a CROSS JOIN, which calculates every possible combination of rows from the two tables.

You can see this by running

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderDetails, Offices
```

In more modern SQL that would be written

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderDetails
CROSS JOIN Offices
```

The SUM() function (without a GROUP BY) runs across all the rows in the result set, regardless of how the resultset was calculated (you can think of the SELECT clause running after the CROSS JOIN).

So your second query takes all the rows created by the CROSS JOIN and sums them up, meaning all the values are counted 7 times.

```
SELECT SUM(OD.quantityOrdered)
FROM OrderDetails as OD
CROSS JOIN Offices as O
```